# Jquery UI button on asp.net mvc 3 nothing happens on Firefox 11

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, uibutton

I am having a button which point to a actionlink that I render with jqueryui button, all I want is the rendering visual of the button, and keeping its normal behavior, on Chrome fine, the button points to the actionlink, but on Firefox 11, when I click the button, nothing happens.

This is the code on the view:

```
<button id="btnNewOffer" style="float: left; margin-left: 30px"> @Html.ActionLink("Offre", "Index", "Service")  </button>
```

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#btnNewOffer").button();
    }) 

</script>
```

This is working on Chrome but non Firefox 11

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use the `<button />` element. You can simply use the `ActionLink` by itself.

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Offre", "Index", "Service", htmlAttributes: new { id = "btnNewOffer", style = "float: left; margin-left: 30px" })
```

Comment: Hi, I tried and it generates this html code (not working), the href is weird: <a class="jqbutton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" style="float: left; margin-left: 30px" href="/?Length=7" role="button">
<span class="ui-button-text">Déposer une offre</span>
</a>

Comment: Hi Uchendu, this code works to create an external css class: @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Index", "Service", null, new { @class = "jqbutton" })